# How to create a macro that subtotals any amount of rows and bring the grand total in the correct row?

Tags: excel, vba, automation

Once a month I do consolidated invoices which we sync from online and format.  I want to automate the format and I have; however, I can't get it to change rows from one invoice to the next because they are never the same. One may be 195 rows and the other 320.

For example, in this part, I need to sort in the D column but not always to row 272. How can I get it to search to whatever point is needed?

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("invoicedetails").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "D2:D272"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal

ActiveCell.Offset(0, -16).Range("A1:P121").Select
Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=4, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(16), _
    Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$D$1:$D$181").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "3821463 Total", "3827540 Total", "3827541 Total", "3827543 Total", "3827544 Total" _
    , "3827556 Total", "3827558 Total", "3827559 Total", "3827560 Total", _
    "3827562 Total", "3827563 Total", "3827564 Total", "3827576 Total", "3827577 Total" _
    , "3827579 Total", "3827580 Total", "3827581 Total", "3827583 Total", _
    "3827584 Total", "3827596 Total", "3848953 Total", "3848980 Total", "3850398 Total" _
    , "3850421 Total", "3863863 Total", "3863864 Total", "3904249 Total", "Grand Total") _
    , Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

This is what records when I do a subtotal for a grand total and the grand total prints about 30 lines down

Answer (score 0):

As long as the D column doesn't have empty spaces inside you can use something like `Range("D1").End(xlDown)` (End.Down) is equivalent to pressing Ctrl + Down) this will return the last cell containing data on an Excel table.

`Range("D1").End(xlDown).Row` will return the row number you need to use

If you do have empty cells within the D column, you may also use an identifier column that has data on every row to get the row.

You can then change the range to include the row simply by concatenating it like do: `Range("D1:D" &  Range("D1").End(xlDown))`

This is not the most elegant solution, but for me its been the most reliable for similar problems. You may also look into the CurrentRegion and UBound atributes which can also help, but as I said I find End to work the best